# How to make Post Request using Smali code?

Tags: java, post, request, smali

Need to make simple `POST` request with one parameter using `org.apache.http.HttpRequest`
in `Smali` code, or something like translate `Java` to `Smali`?
Code like that, but in Smali.

```
HttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.createDefault();
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.mywebsite.com");
List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("param-1", "12345"));
httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params, "UTF-8"));
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
```

Comment: Can you be more specific what sort request do you need to do?

Comment: I edited, simple request like that.